# Irreducible polynomial solutions in radicals.

Tags: polynomials, radicals, irreducible-polynomials

Assume we have irreducible polynomial of degree greater or equal 5. Is it true that this polynomial has no solution in radicals?

Comment: Not in general, but could have in special cases, e.g. the polynomial $(x^7-1)/(x-1)$ would have a solution in terms of radicals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For example, $x^5 + 2$ has root $\sqrt[5]{-2}$.

Comment: Thanks, these are trivial cases. But is there any non-trivial case?

Comment: Yes, e.g. $x^5+5 x^4+5 x^3-5 x^2-5 x-3$.

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan Can you define what you mean by trivial? For example is $$(x+237)^5+2$$ trivial?

Comment: Actually under the trivial I understand the equations obviously solvable in radicals. $(x+a)^p=k$ is obviously solvable, while the $x^5+5 x^4+5 x^3-5 x^2-5 x-3=0$ is not. Sorry for confusion of course.

Comment: BTW, if you're wondering about $x^5+5x^4+5x^3-5x^2-5x-3$, the substitution $x = t + 1/t - 1$ turns it into $t^5 + 1/t^5 - 4$, which has "obvious" solutions in radicals.